# Loading assets from *.blade.php in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

Laravel 5.4 here.

I added test.css file under public/css/ and then made a call in my layout.blade.php like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/test.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

but the asset does not get loaded.

My problem is that i am trying to run css for jquery-ui. I downloaded jquery-ui-bundle via npm and then required it in resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js. Widget works, but the calendar shows up without styles. So i try to add styles manually by referencing them directly through the template. Unfortunately, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly put js/CSS into your public folder if they don't require compiling first (which is in your case) - There is no harm in that

But if you want to go as per recommendation:

- Pull library using NPM,
- Add js/CSS into gulpfile.js which you want to copy to the public folder:

  elixir((mix) => {

  ```
  mix.sass('app.scss')
  .webpack('app.js')
  .mix.copy('node_modules/foo/bar.css', 'public/css/bar.css');
  ```

  });

  https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#copying-files-and-directories
- Run `npm run` command
- And then include into your blade view like:

  `<link href="{{ asset('css/bar.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, you can just simply copy source file to `public\css` or `public\js` and link it to your project file. In other words, link

```
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href={{asset('css/bootstrap.css')}}
```